# Axios onDownloadProgress (on get method) gets called only once and setTimeout in callback never gets called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, axios, progress-bar

I am trying to show progress bar while fetching API from backend. It seems to work however there are a couple of issues that I cannot solve. a) progress bar goes from 0 to 100 and does not show any progress as onDownloadProgress gets fired only once. b) I want to have setTimeout because sometimes loading API is so fast that progress bar disappears right after the application starts to run. I naively thought having setTimeout prevents this problem because I can pause the whole process after fetching API is done. Since setTime out never gets fired, loading remains true and progress bar never goes away.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    // grab rooms from back end
    fetchRooms();
  }, []);

const fetchRooms = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get(`${ENDPOINT}/api/rooms`, {
        onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          setProgress(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / totalLength));
          if (progress === 100) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("load finished!////////");
              setLoading(false);
            }, 2000);
          }
        },
      });
     
      setRooms(res.data);
      // having setLoading here dose not work as progress bar disappears right after application starts to run if loading is too fast
      // setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setProgress(0);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can the setInterval JavaScript function inside the setProgress function, and an html progress tag.  The following is an example of how to using some of your code.  The list.json file is just an array of objects.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ENDPOINT =
  "./list.json";

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    // grab rooms from back end
    fetchRooms();
  }, [progress]);

  const fetchRooms = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get(`${ENDPOINT}`, {
        onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100)/progressEvent.total);
          setProgress(setInterval(percentCompleted,10)) // progress is set every 10 milliseconds
        },
      });

      setRooms(res.data.results);
      console.log(rooms);
      // having setLoading here dose not work as progress bar disappears right after application starts to run if loading is too fast
      // setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setProgress(0);
    }
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <progress value={progress} max="100"/>
  }
  return null;
}

export default App;
```

References:

W3Schools. How TO - JavaScript Progress Bar. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp. (Accessed 7 May 2021).